# Child rigidbody on an animated transform inherits the movement as a velocity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to code myself a sliding mechanic for a character controller and have added functionality for moving platforms.

My current setup is for the moving platform to have an unscaled parent that I animate using an Animator so that my character doesn't stretch because of inherited scale/rotation when I parent it to the platform.

When I start sliding I run this piece of code in my state machine:

```
public override void EnterState()
{
    slideVelocity = cont.rigid.velocity.magnitude / Time.fixedDeltaTime; //There is some more code here but all it does is set the direction of the player to look in the direction of movement.
}
```

I don't know why but the rigidbodies velocity seems to be zero when I look at it in the inspector but when I initiate sliding it's not.
The player moves as if they have inherited the movement vector of the parent:
[Youtube Video](https://youtu.be/PZHhGRdMIDA)

I tried subtracting a movement delta of my platform from the slide velocity calculation but it didn't seem to work.

```
Vector3 velCalc = Vector3.zero ;

if (sets.platform) // Sets is a general class that manages generic logic and settings for all the states.
{
    velCalc = - sets.platform.delta;
}
slideVelocity = (cont.rigid.velocity + velCalc).magnitude / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
```